# Ionic 3 storage set and get acting weird

Tags: ionic3, ionic-storage

I have an Ionic 3 app, where I store an array of objects in SQLite.

My this.data array (explained in the lower section) looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        guid: "xy",
        images: [
            { guid: 0, uploaded: true },
            { guid: 1, uploaded: true }
        ],
    },
    {
        guid: "xz",
        images: [
            { guid: 0, uploaded: false },
            { guid: 1, uploaded: false }
        ],
    }
]
```

So an object has a guid and an array of objects again. After an item is updated I want to save all the items to the storage as well as to the uploader class' variable. The uploader class has a this.data and this.key property.

Here is a snippet from the problematic part:

```ts
updateItem(value){
    // search for the index of the item in the array
    var index = this.data.findIndex((item) => {
        return item.guid == value.guid;
    });

    if(index >= 0){
        // update the item in the array with the changed one
        this.data[index] = value;

        // this works fine, prints with the updated item
        console.log(this.data);

        // it supposed to save the whole array with the changed items
        return this.storage.set(this.key, this.data).then(() => {

            // for debug I read the data again - same happens after app restart
            this.storage.get(this.key).then((data) => {
                // this logs the initial, unchanged items
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }

    return Promise.reject(new Error('error'));
}
```

First, it searches for the index of the item in the `this.data` array, if found, then overrides the item in the array.
Then it tries to save it into the storage.
For debugging purposes, I read the storage and console.log it.

After I set the "xz" object's images to `uploaded = true`, I call the `updateItem(secondItem)`.

From the first `console.log` I see that "xy" and "xy" object's images are all uploaded: true. The storage.set called, and inside the storage.get, the initial state occurs. The "xy" object's images are uploaded: true, but the "xz" object's are false.
After I restart my app, this state loads again.

If there is only one object in this.data, the updateItem works fine, for example, I set the storage with uploaded: false, then I change the attributes, and call `updateItem(firstItem)`, it saves the uploaded state. But if there is more than one object in the array, it only saves one.

I tried to save it as JSON, and parse when I read it back, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up cloning the array, then saving the clone and then assign the clone to the original array. This solved my problem.

```ts
updateItem(value){
    // search for the index of the item in the array
    var index = this.data.findIndex((item) => {
        return item.guid == value.guid;
    });

    var newData = this.data.slice();

    if(index >= 0){
        // update the item in the array with the changed one
        newData[index] = value;

        // it supposed to save the whole array with the changed items
        return this.storage.set(this.key, newData).then(() => {
            this.data = newData;

            // for debug I read the data again - same happens after app restart
            this.storage.get(this.key).then((data) => {
                // this logs the initial, unchanged items
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    }

    return Promise.reject(new Error('error'));
}
```